# explode of nested array and storing in individual row is taking too much time using pyspark data frame

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I using the below code snippet to explode the columns from a dataframe created out of nested json. the query is taking too much time to complete. can i get some suggestion as how to improve the performance. I tried to increase the cluster size however that as well did not help since code 52 was a significant issue i was facing

here is the code i am using:

```
`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode, lit, when
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("YourAppName").config("spark.executor.memory", "4g").getOrCreate()

search_query = search_query.repartition(100)  # Adjust the number according to your data size.

search_query = search_query.limit(1000)  # Adjust the limit according to your needs

column_names = [
    "col1",
    "col2",
    "col3",
    "col4",
    "col5",
    "col6",
    "col7",
    "col8",
    "col9",
    "col10",
    "col11",
    "col12",
  
]


initial_schema = StructType([StructField(name, StringType(), True) for name in column_names])

for col_name in column_names:
    search_query = search_query.withColumn(
        col_name,
        when(col(f"prejson.results.{col_name}").isNotNull(), col(f"prejson.results.{col_name}"))
        .when(col(f"prejson.sBrand.{col_name}").isNotNull(), col(f"prejson.sBrand.{col_name}"))
        .when(col(f"prejson.sVideo.{col_name}").isNotNull(), col(f"prejson.sVideo.{col_name}"))
        .otherwise(None)
    )

for col_name in column_names:
    search_query = search_query .withColumn(col_name, explode(col(col_name)))

results= search_query .select(column_names)
print(results.show())`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 34.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 34.0 (TID 911) (10.99.0.8 executor 47): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

thats the major issue since it takes too much time and never shares the results due the above issue

Comment: can you please add input and expected output ?

Comment: please add sample `prejson` and your expected output ?

Comment: |-- result_json: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- results: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col1 string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Brand: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col1 string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Video: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- col1 string (nullable = true)
thats the schema type all the array have similar columns

Comment: @sitohnabanaerjee Could you add the schema in a readable format to the question body?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: a final dataframe which will have columns data from respective array i.e
col1                      
data from results array      
data from Brand  array
data from Video   array 
col2                      
data from results  array 
data from Brand array 
data from Video array

Comment: let say `col1` is available in all of three array columns.. in that case which one do you take ?

Comment: so a dataframe with data from all the array under column1 (col1)

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to answer this without a sample of `prejson` data or context about the data you're working with, but I have an idea about what the problem may be that needed more space to explain than what fits in a comment.

I think the piece of code that's causing the memory overflow error is:

```
for col_name in column_names:
    search_query = search_query .withColumn(col_name, explode(col(col_name)))
```

Take this example:
First I'm exploding like it's described in the question. It causes the dataframe to grow exponentially; because, you're creating one row for all possible permutation lists elements.

Then I'm exploding like the lists are zips; meaning that each element of a list is corresponding to one element of other list(s) - the element with the same index.

Usually when multiple columns are being exploded, the second method is the target rather than the first.

```
# exploding like it's described in the question
initial_df = (
    spark.createDataFrame([
        ([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"])
    ], ['c1', 'c2'])
)
print("input dataframe:")
initial_df.show()

column_names = initial_df.columns
for col_name in column_names:
    initial_df = initial_df.withColumn(col_name, f.explode(col_name))
initial_df.show()
print(f"final record count: {initial_df.count()}")

# exploding like each element of an array is corresponding to one element of the other array (like a zip)
initial_df = (
    spark.createDataFrame([
        ([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"])
    ], ['c1', 'c2'])
)
initial_df = (
    initial_df
    .withColumn("zipped", f.explode(f.arrays_zip("c1", "c2")))
    .select("zipped.*")
)
initial_df.show()
print(f"final record count: {initial_df.count()}")
```

And the output:

```
input dataframe:
+---------+---------+                                                           
|       c1|       c2|
+---------+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|[a, b, c]|
+---------+---------+

+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  1|  b|
|  1|  c|
|  2|  a|
|  2|  b|
|  2|  c|
|  3|  a|
|  3|  b|
|  3|  c|
+---+---+
final record count: 9
                                                           
+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  2|  b|
|  3|  c|
+---+---+
final record count: 3
```